# Minimum of 2 DateTime in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to find the minimum of 2 DateTime objects in Rails?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The most rubyish way is to use

```
[a, b].min
```

but you could also use the C-style

```
(a > b)? b : a
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Zabba  Enumerable.min uses the `<=>` operator behind the scenes, so it'll work on just about anything.  Or you can pass it a block, if you want to get fancy: `[aa, bb, cc].min {|a, b| a.foo <=> b.foo}`

Comment: Note this fails if either date is nil. If you can be certain one of them is not nil, you can make the other fall back to it, e.g. to ensure a date is not in the future: `[inputtedDate||DateTime.now, DateTime.now].min`

Comment: You can also do `[a, b].select(&:present?).min` to handle/ignore `nil` values.

Comment: @jfeust - If you're only worried about getting rid of `nil`s then `[a, b].compact.min` is even cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
d1 = DateTime.parse("2010-10-10")
d2 = DateTime.parse("2011-10-10")
min = d1 < d2 ? d1 : d2
```

Comment: Yes, I could do that.. :), but I was wondering, is there not a method for this in Ruby/Rails ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to quickly find the lower date in two or more dates you can do the following:

`[a, b, c].compact.min`

The `compact` will remove nil dates and makes sure you don't get an exception.
If you are looking to find the most recent date you can:

`[a, b, c].compact.max`